# AWS CDK version not displaying in Terminal

Tags: python, terminal, aws-cdk

I am using Node.js version 14.15.1 on my Mac. I installed the AWS CDK using

```html
sudo npm install -g aws-cdk
```

When I check my cdk version, the output is just "cdk" without telling me the version

```html
% cdk --version
cdk
```

When I try to initialize a sample app in python, I get this result rather than the [expected result in the tutorial I am following](https://cdkworkshop.com/30-python/20-create-project/100-cdk-init.html#cdk-init).

```html
% cdk init sample-app --language python

Usage:
  cdk [-vbo] [--toc] [--notransition] [--logo=<logo>] [--theme=<theme>] [--custom-css=<cssfile>] FILE
  cdk --install-theme=<theme>
  cdk --default-theme=<theme>
  cdk --generate=<name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely there is something else called `cdk` ahead of the nodejs `aws-cdk` package in your path. You can use the `which` command to figure out what path is actually being called when you run `cdk.` On my system, the nodejs `aws-cdk` package gets installed to `/usr/local/bin/cdk`.

Try running `which cdk` and if you find that your shell tells you it's running a different `cdk` binary, uninstall whatever that package is and retry.

Comment: That worked! Turns out I had a different cdk I'd installed via conda, so after uninstalling that (or specifying the complete path name) it worked!